# An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Помогите пожалуйста понять, почему у меня следующая ошибка:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in ConsoleApplication2.exe"

в классе Field, в сеттере свойства X?

```
class Game
{
    static void StartGame()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Введите спавн Х игрока");
        int Player_X = Convert.ToInt32((Console.ReadLine()));
        Console.WriteLine("Введите спавн Y игрока");
        int Player_Y = Convert.ToInt32((Console.ReadLine()));

        Console.Clear();

        Bomb[] Bombs = new Bomb[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < Bombs.Length; i++)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            Bombs[i] = new Bomb(r.Next(1, 20), r.Next(1, 20));
        }

        Field field = new Field(20, 20, Bombs, new Player(Player_X, Player_Y, 'd'), 0, 0 );
        field.MakeField();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StartGame();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}


class Bomb
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;

    public Bomb(int X, int Y)
    {
        this.X = X;
        this.Y = Y;
    }
}

class Field
{
    Bomb[] Bombs { get { return Bombs; } set { for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++) { bool acceptable = true; if (!(value[i].X > this.X && value[i].Y > this.Y && value[i].X < this.X + Width && value[i].Y < this.Y + Height)) { acceptable = false; } if (acceptable) Bombs = value; } } }
    int Height;
    int Width;
    Player player;
    int X { get { return X; } set { if (value >= 0) X = value; } }
    int Y { get { return Y; } set { if (value >= 0) Y = value; } }

    public Field(int Height, int Width, Bomb[] Bombs, Player player, int x, int y)
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
        this.Bombs = Bombs;
        this.Height = Height; // Y -- start, Y + Height -- end
        this.Width = Width; // X -- start, X + Width -- end
        this.player = player;
    }

    public void MakeField()
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(X, Y);
        for (int i = 1, j = 1; i <= Height; i++)
        {
            if (j > 9)
                j = 1;
            Console.WriteLine(j);
            j++;
        }
        for (int i = 1, j = 1; i <= Width; i++)
        {
            if (j > 9)
                j = 1;
            Console.Write(j);
            j++;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < Bombs.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(Bombs[i].X, Bombs[i].Y);
            Console.Write('B');
        }
        Console.SetCursorPosition(player.X, player.Y);
        Console.Write('P');
    }
    public void IsOver()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Bombs.Length; i++)
        {
            if (player.X == Bombs[i].X && player.Y == Bombs[i].Y)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(Width + 50, Height + 50);
                Console.WriteLine("You\'ve lost!");
            }
        }
    }
    public void PrintPlayer()
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(player.X, player.Y);
        Console.WriteLine('Y');
    }
}

class Player_CT : Player
{
    public Player_CT(int x, int y, char d) : base(x, y, d) { }

    bool DefuseKits; // defuse the bomb with defuse kits - 5 seconds, without - 10 seconds
    int hp { get { return hp; } set { if (hp > -1 && hp < 101) hp = value; } } // hp range = (0, 100)

    public void DefuseBomb(Bomb bomb)
    {
        if (this.X - bomb.X <= 2 && this.Y - bomb.Y <= 2) // находится в двух точках от бомбы
        {
            if (DefuseKits)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                bomb = null; // bomb doesnt exist anymore
            }
            else
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
                bomb = null;
            }
        }
    }
    public void TakeDefuseKit(DefuseKit[] defusekits)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < defusekits.Length; i++)
        {
            if (this.X - defusekits[i].X <= 2 && this.Y - defusekits[i].Y <= 2)
            {
                DefuseKits = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

class DefuseKit
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;
}


class Player
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;
    public char direct
    {
        get
        {
            return direct;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == 'w')
                direct = 'u';
            else if (value == 'd')
                direct = 'r';
            else if (value == 'a')
                direct = 'l';
            else if (value == 's')
                direct = 'd';
        }
    }  // u - up; d - down; l - left; r - right; WASD - W - up A - left S - down D - right

    public Player(int x, int y, char d)
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
        this.direct = d;
    }
    public void Move()
    {
        //ConsoleKeyInfo a = Console.ReadKey();
        //direct = a.KeyChar;
        int X1 = this.X;
        int Y1 = this.Y;
        if (direct == 'u')
        {
            this.Y += 1;
        }
        else if (direct == 'd')
        {
            this.Y -= 1;
        }
        else if (direct == 'r')
        {
            this.X += 1;
        }
        else if (direct == 'l')
        {
            this.Y -= 1;
        }
        Console.SetCursorPosition(X1, Y1);
        Console.Write(' ');
    }
}
```

Comment: У вас рекурсия.  `int X { get { return X; } set { if (value >= 0) X = value; } }` вот последнее присваивание накоротко замыкает  сетер. Вы расчитываете на авто-свойство, но записав выражение - теряете этот функционал. Приёдется обьявить `_x` или что-то подобное для этой цели в гетере и сетере.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так делать нельзя

> int X { get { return X; } set { if (value >= 0) X = value; } }

потому что `return X;` - вызывает безконечную рекурсию гетера, и `X = value;` - тоже вызывает безконечную рекурсию сетера X (StackOverflowException).

вот так делать можно (привожу в пример, что б было понятно откуда появляется впечатление что Х можно свободно использовать, только в случае ниже, его можно свободно использовать)

```
int X { get ;  set ; }
```

это "автоматическое" обьявление свойства.

Что бы исправить ошибку, нужно обьявить вспомагательный х. Можно _х что б не "смешивать". Можно х-маленький. Например так

```
int _x;
int _y;
int X { get { return _x; } set { if (value >= 0) _x = value; } }
int Y { get { return _y; } set { if (value >= 0) _y = value; } }
```

Comment: я уже дописал ответ.

Comment: можете еще помочь понять, почему у меня при создании бомб в методе StartGame() класса Game они все остаются null? на 94 строке мне вышла ошибка An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in ConsoleApplication4.exe, потому что бомбы были нулл, но я ведь туда добавляю рандомные интеджеры.

Comment: В сеттер условие поставили: if (acceptable) Bombs = value; а если  не acceptable,  то соответственно  Bombs останется null.

Comment: нет, у меня условие подходит под acceptable.

Comment: Думайте где допустили "логическую" ошибку. Те которые имеют acceptable=false - там у вас null.